# Excel - Highlight Rows based on look up value from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Hi I have an excel sheet, that has a column called as Company name

[image: List of my Companies]

in another sheet there is there are couple of look ups.. i need to look up those and highlight them in different colors based on the look up list.

[image]

for example, in the above scenario, i need Company A Highligted in oone color and company C in another.

If highlighting is challgeng, i dont mind even having a seperate coloumn next to it that says, if it is a partner or competitor.

i tried the below formula under conditional formatting .. but doesnt work for different colours... it colors everything the same

```
=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1,'Lookup List'!$A$2:$D$200,1,FALSE)))
```

Comment: I you want different color you will need to create more rules, one for each color desired.

Comment: But that conditional formatting should not use the same color for all cells but should color some and others not. For me the function works (except of the fact that in Excel 2003 the condition cannot access data from other worksheets).

Answer (score 1):

Please try selecting Company Name column and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIF('Lookup List'!$A:$A,B1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select colour Fill (highlight) of your choice, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Then repeat with:

```
=COUNTIF('Lookup List'!$B:$B,B1)
```

with a different fill.

If *every* entry is one colour or the other then one CF rule is sufficient, with the other colour applied as standard fill.